# position absolute div from middle instead of edges

Tags: css, css-position

I have an absolutely positioned div of variable width that I want to position to be at a certain x position within the parent (relative) div.  I can do this by setting

```
left: 50px
```

however I want the element to be centered on the 50px mark, instead of having its left or right edge be at 50px.  I can do this with javascript by getting the width and setting it manually, but is there a way to do this using only CSS?  (preferably not using transform and other newer features, although I'll take what I can get)

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from things that are still unstable

Comment: If you don't have a fixed width and if you don't want to use transforms, then you have to use JavaScript, if you don't want to use JavaScript, then you have to use transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the transform property to "translate" the element by 50% of its width to the left:

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can still use `left:50px` but add

```
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

which will drag the element back 50% of it's own width..regardless of what that is.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px; transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
  top:0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  </div>
```